# mongodb java driver using last in group Aggregates

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My mongodb collection "events" include 3 fields: number, date, type. What I want to know is how many "events" has the most recent date for their number (I mean they are the most updated events for this number) and has type=3.

My query in mongo is working, but I don't know how to turn it to java using the java driver, since I don't understand what are the parameters of Accumulators.last function (and couldn't find any examples!) I know I can just write it as a string but I prefer using the mongodb java driver API. In mongo the query is:

```
db.events.aggregate([ 
  {$sort:{date:1}}, 
  {$group: {
    _id: {"number" : "$number"},
    "recent" : {$last: {action:"$$ROOT.type"}}
  }}, 
  {$match: {"recent.action" : 3}}, 
  {$count: "Qty"} 
],{allowDiskUse: true});
```

What I tried to write is:

```
Bson stage1 =  Aggregates.sort(Sorts.orderBy(Sorts.ascending("date")));
Bson stage2 = Aggregates.group("$number", Accumulators.last("recent", Accumulators.push("recentEvent", "$$ROOT")));
Bson deleteType = Filters.eq("recent.recentEvent.type", 3);
Bson stage3 = Aggregates.match(deleteType );
Bson stage4 = Aggregates.count("numberOfLastDelete");
pipeline = Arrays.asList(stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4);
result = collection.aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(true).useCursor(true);
Document lastDeleteNumDoc = result.iterator().next();
```

This is not working and I get an error in the last line:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.BsonField.

If I don't use the API for the group, this code is working:

```
    Bson stage1 =  Aggregates.sort(Sorts.ascending("date"));

    String groupString =
            "{" +
                "$group:" +
                "{" +
                    "_id: \"$number\", " +
                    "\"recent\": { $last: {lastType:\"$$ROOT.type\"} } " +
                "}" +
            "}";


    Bson stage2 = Document.parse(groupString);
    Bson deleteType = Filters.eq("recent.type",3);
    Bson stage3 = Aggregates.match(deleteType );
    Bson stage4 = Aggregates.count("numberOfLastDelete");
    pipeline = Arrays.asList(stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4);
    result = collection.aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(true).useCursor(true);
    Document lastDeleteNumDoc = result.iterator().next();
    Integer lastDeleteNum = lastDeleteNumDoc.getInteger("numberOfLastDelete");
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Osnat

Comment: Show a small sample of the documents you have and the result you would expect from that sample. Even your shell operation has various wrong looking things in it, so it might be better to look at the whole problem from scratch. Appreciate you have made an effort though.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the shell. Also, I have added the code that did work in java but don't use the API